# max number of columns in a mysql table error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have reached the limit set on the row size of a table, so I'm not able to add any more columns to the table.

I'm getting the following error:

> .#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to
>   TEXT or BLOBs

I have researched this issue on the [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html), but am still unsure about how to fix this problem.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue, and what setting or script that I would need to run to modify the setting so it allows me to add more columns to the table?

Comment: Thou art the man! That's really impressive.

Answer (score 3):

Why is your row size 64k to begin with?  That is your problem. Not  the setting being too low.

From:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html

> Each table has an .frm file that contains the table definition. The
>   server uses the following expression to check some of the table
>   information stored in the file against an upper limit of 64KB:

```
> if (info_length+(ulong) create_fields.elements*FCOMP+288+
>     n_length+int_length+com_length > 65535L || int_count > 255)
```

So it's not likely something you can easily change (short of modifying source code and running a custom  MySQL.   Give us your schema and we might be able to better advise, but the short answer would seem to be that you have too many columns, or need to change some VARCHARs etc. to be text/blob.

Without seeing the (likely abomination of a) schema, it's hard to advise.

Comment: +1 for explanation. However, I don't agree with word 'likely' and 'schema' in your last sentence. I used to think that having more than 10-20 columns is usually is a break of one or the other normal form or design problem (even without looking into details). But reaching the limits of field number... It's beyond my understanding.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by updating some of the columns from varchar to text.